# Add an object to an array in a specific index

Tags: javascript, object, associative-array

How can I add an object to a new empty array, in a specific index.

Let's say "0"

I have a forEach loop and I build an object with it

```
var array = [];

 var myObject = {
    value1: value1,
    value2: value2
 };
```

I can generate as many "myObject" as the times the forEach loops

How can I add all those "myObject" into "array" on the index "0"?

Comment: object with index?

Comment: Do you mean one Array?

Comment: Updated the question @WashingtonGuedes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Square brackets to the rescue:

```
var obj = {}
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   if (!obj["val"+i]) {
     obj["val"+i] = []
   }
   obj["val"+i].push("val"+i)
}
```

Comment: That will replace the value in the index "0" with another value in each loop. I want to push it or add it so at the end in the position "0" I will have multiple arrays.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: I was missing the conditional validation :) now it's working, thanks Alexey